# How to move a domain from Godaddy to AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Since Godaddy went down for some hours my client and I are very upset and want to change everything to AWS.

Everything is done so far, only the domains (blablabla.com) are missing, I'm having a hard time trying to migrate from godaddy to Route 53, Do I have to remove from one and create from scratch from AWS?

Does anyone have any experience on how to do this?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

the solution:

Login on your aws console;
Click on Route 53;
Create Hosted Zone;
Select your new created host title and click "Go to Record Sets", take note of the nameservers;

Login on your Godaddy account;
Select your domain;
Go to Nameservers and click SetNameservers;
paste all the four you took from "Go to Record Sets" Route 53;

and that's it..., you don't have to rely on this horrible service Godaddy provides anymore

Comment: Is there a way to transfer the actual domain over? (not just set the nameservers on GoDaddy registrar) ie. if i want to close my GoDaddy account completely. ?

Comment: so far I am concern, Amazon doesn't provide registar, that's why I have account on both

Comment: That's right, you can transfer ownership to another registrar like Dreamhost or something else you like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but did you copy each into a separate line? I still notice my website is up on goDaddy's server... does it take time for this to go into effect?

Comment: Actually I noticed it added a period at the end of the domain name.. is that to be expected?

Comment: You can now transfer domains over to Route 53.  It is transparently handled with Amazon's partner "Gandi".  But all over your interfacing with the domain happens via the Route 53 UI.

Comment: I think you should also unlock this domain from godaddy

Comment: See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/registrar.html - you can do registration through Amazon now.

Answer (score 22):

You can transfer the domain registration to AWS Route 53.
You have to "unlock" the account.

Log On to Go Daddy.

Go to *Domain Details* Then *Settings*:

- Lock: Set to Off
- Authorization Code: Email My Code

Route 53 will need the authorization code to complete the transfer request.

Answer (score 7):

Here are the steps to migrate your internet domain name to AWS route 53 (DNS Manager).

** Be careful where your mail server is hosted, either in the Godaddy mail service, Gmail (gsuite) or in your Cpanel server (VPS/Server). 
 ** To empower your Domain DNS capabilities, you need to transfer the name servers, DNS records and domain name to AWS route53, thats why it's recommended to move to AWS Route 53. You can keep Godaddy to be owner of your yourdomain.com and manage your DNS by Route 53

STEPS:

1. Go to Godaddy DNS records and understand each of them and note them (Take a screenshot)
2. Go to AWS route 53, Crete a Public hosted Zone (Create your domain on AWS route 53).  Here is a good tutorial about it:

https://www.clickittech.com/aws/migrate-godaddy-to-aws-route53/

3. Copy your Godaddy DNs records into your Public hosted zone previously created. Remember, each record needs to exist in the new aws zone.
4. Change your Name Servers to AWS Route 53. What does it means? In order to allow AWS route 53 to manage your domain, DNs records, etc. you need to change your actual Godadaddy Name server (NS) Records to AWS Records.

   - Go to Godaddy admin Panel and Login
   - Go to DNS Management
   - Under Name Servers Click on Change - > Custom - > Change Name Servers

   You need to change from NSx.domaincontrol.com to the AWS Name servers.

More info: https://www.clickittech.com/aws/migrate-godaddy-to-aws-route53/

After 4-8 hours your Name Servers will be reflected and propagated around your country, world and networks.

Practically you are done with this.

Additionally, if you need to migrate your website or web app to AWS go to this tutorial, great explanation, see below:

https://www.clickittech.com/aws-migration/transfer-domain-aws-migrate-move-website-aws/

Answer (score 2):

The answer from [The Poet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1248959/the-poet) above is good for moving everything, but it will also kill your email service with GoDaddy. If you want to keep the email servers running at GoDaddy, you will also need to get your MX email servers and their priority numbers. Mine looked like this...

```
0 smtp.secureserver.net
10 mailstore1.secureserver.net
```

Take these over to your Route53 settings, click Create Record Set, choose a type of MX Mail Exchange, and paste these values in (with the number in the front as shown above). Save the record set.

Also [PJT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118566/pjt) was correct; all domain info in Route53 ends with an extra period for some reason specific to AWS, but don't worry about it--it doesn't affect production behavior. When you copy your four from Route53 to paste in GoDaddy's Name Servers, you will need to do them one at a time and trim off the extra period at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to migrate your DNS records to Route 53, you'll need to [export them from GoDaddy](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/export-my-domains-zone-file-records-4166) and recreate them manually in Route 53.

To do this in one automated step, consider a DNS migration tool such as DNSTools.ninja, as outlined here: https://dnstools.ninja/migrate-bind-aws-route53-safely-3-commands/

Answer (score 1):

**Be careful with google mx records if you have them.**

#### Why switch to route 53?

1. AWS Route 53 doesn’t limit you to 64 subdomain.
2. AWS allows you to host buckets with route 53

It all comes at a 50 cent/month.

#### AWS Nameservers

Now to answer your question, you need move the name servers to route 53. That means in godaddy name server section should be filled with aws name servers.
See the steps here.
https://metamug.com/article/dns-migrate-godaddy-to-route-53.php

Answer (score 0):

The detailed steps to transfer the domain registrar from GoDaddy to Route 53 is given at https://cloudopian.com/blog/how-to-transfer-domain-registrar-from-godaddy-to-amazon-route-53/

Remember, you first need to transfer your name servers by creating a hosted zone in Route 53 and pointing your godaddy hosted domain to use Route 53's name servers instead of it's own name servers.