# Route53 route subdomain to AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, cname, amazon-route53, aws-lambda

I want to route my.domain.com to the url of my lambda function (which I setup and working via the API Gateway). I can't seem to be able to do this. I also can't seem to be able to to CNAME to anything (so my.domain.com results in a dns error when I CNAME it to domain.com).
The normal url (domain.com) is routed to a static S3 bucket and is fine.

The domain was bought on GoDaddy. I changed it so that my GoDaddy Name Servers point to those in a Host Zone which I set up via Route53.

Comment: What do you mean by "the URL of my Lambda function"? Are you accessing Lambda via an API Gateway configuration?

Comment: For your `CNAME` issue, have you configured your GoDaddy name servers to point to Amazon Route 53? For example, [How to move a domain from Godaddy to AWS Route 53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433420/how-to-move-a-domain-from-godaddy-to-aws-route-53)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes I am. I also configured my GoDaddy name servers to point to Route53 like in the example. Updated the question to clarify this for future readers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't make a CNAME on domain root ie. `domain.com` because it's zone apex.

To be able to do what you're looking for you need to make a CNAME `example.domain.com` pointing to `CloudFront` endpoint generated by `API Gateway`.

You can follow more detailed [API Gateway domain setup instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html).